# How to define a dependency in SBT with an extension and a classifier?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, ivy

I am trying to find an example of how to define a dependency in SBT that has both an extension and a classifier. So far, I haven't found such an example, just one that has a classifier. Is "extension"  called differently in SBT?

I am guessing this should be supported, because SBT is using Ivy underneath and Ivy supports this. Also, SBT is using Maven dependencies and Maven has this (although it's called "type" in the Maven world).

Could somebody please show me a working example of this basic thing?